# jQuery navigation assistance

Tags: jquery

Updated to fix the markup issue :/

http://jsfiddle.net/G7p2U/1/ that is the link to better understand everything

jQuery I am using is

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".crumbs a").each( function() {
    $(this).append('<div class="indicator"></div>');
  });
var i = 0;
var linkpos= new Array("0,0", "0,110", "0,220", "0,330", "0,440", "0,550", "0,660");
    $(".crumbs").each( function() {
 var s = linkpos[i];
 var x = s.split(",");
 var t = x[0];
 var l = x[1];
$(this).css({ "top":t+"px", "left":l+"px" });
 i++;
 }); 
});
```

Problem is that when this was written it worked correctly, now there is the issue. Before the markup was like so

```
 <div class="pun-crumbs">
    <div class="crumbs">
     <a href="#">Index</a>
   </div>
  <div class="crumbs">
     <a href="#">Profile</a>
  </div>
     <div class="crumbs">
       <a href="#">Recent</a>
    </div>
    <div class="crumbs">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
   </div>
 </div>​
```

Though that is not how the PHP parse's the data markup it actually comes out like so

```
 <div class="pun-crumbs">
   <div class="crumbs">
     <a href="#">Index</a>
      <a href="#">Profile</a>
        <a href="#">Recent</a>
         <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>​
```

So my trouble is now for some reason I can not get the links to separate like I need them too..

should look like so
http://jsfiddle.net/nXrDn/

Any help?

​

Comment: The second code block represents invalid HTML...the outer `<div>` isn't closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/G7p2U/4/)

You can reproduce your original markup starting from the new HTML by running the following script to prepare the elements:

```
$(".crumbs > a").unwrap();
$(".pun-crumbs > a").wrap("<div class='crumbs' />");
```

All you have to do is put this first in your document ready handler, before your current code, as shown in the demo.

This is pretty intuitive: it removes the `.crumbs` div (unwraps its children), then wraps each one in a new `.crumbs` div.

Comment: very nice nbrooks thank you. It says I can accept in 3 minutes, and I'll be sure to do so.Thank you very much.

Comment: nice, I didn't know about the unwrap function

Comment: could I ask for more assistance on something?

Comment: @user1760670 Sure no problem. Amir -- Yes, it's useful on occasion, see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap)

Comment: I need to get rid of these raques or whatever they look like so >>  &raquo;

Comment: also seems to be an issue with something please take a look here http://zombienerds.forumotion.com/t8-sdfsdfsdfsdfdsf

Comment: @user1760670 Based on the rendered markup, php is adding some extra characters to the output that weren't in your post...you can remove all text (and other) nodes using `$('.pun-crumbs').children(':not(.crumbs)').remove()`

Comment: this seems to not be working correctly. I placed it in a document ready function and added ; at the end of the .remove(); but nothing changed. 

Also for some reason nbrooks, the bottom crumbs is completely messed up. Is there any way to create this so both work perfectly?

Comment: Did rendering without the extra characters work correctly before with your original markup, or has it always been a problem? Also your bottom breadcrumbs have a different class (`pun-crumbs2`), plus their inner markup is different -- (no `crumbs` div to unwrap). Either make them consistent (*better*) or copy the script and re-run it for the second one (*not ideal*)

Comment: what is that the bottom crumb? no. and the markup is not mine, it is parsed through the php. The website link i gave you provides the ugly visual lol

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21620/discussion-between-nbrooks-and-user1760670)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/G7p2U/12/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$(".crumbs").addClass("crumby").removeClass("crumbs")
$(".crumby a").wrap('<div class="crumbs" />');
$(".crumbs a").each( function() {
//rest of code
```